# ClickOnce for .NET Framework application with side-by-side dependencies in manifest

Tags: manifest, clickonce, visual-studio-2022, side-by-side, regfreecom

I'm trying to create a clickonce deployment for my .NET Framework (4.8) application in VS2022.

The application is using some COM components using a side-by-side configuration (having several  entries in my app.manifest file: some 3rd-party components and one reference to "Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 6.0.

Building and running the application works and the side-by-side components can be used.

As soon as I try publishing the app using clickonce, suddenly the app won't build anymore because I get MSB3113 errors (File so-and-so not found) for all the assembly references in my application manifest.

Does anyone know what's going on and how you can deploy such an application using ClickOnce?

Edit: Added more detail information.
It's a .NET Framework (4.8) application.
The app.manifest contains this dependency (among others)

```xml
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

When I start publishing, git shows that the .csproj entry `<GenerateManifests>` gets changed from `false` to `true`.

The build process then fails with this error:

```
2>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: foobar, Konfiguration: Release x86 ------
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): error MSB3113: Die Datei "Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=*, PublicKeyToken=6595b64144ccf1df, ProcessorArchitecture=*, Type=win32" wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I get the same error for every other dependency I have in my app.manifest and for which all the neccessary files are being copied to the output folder during a regular build.

Comment: Meanwhile I've performed a lot of additional tests, including trying to ClickOnce-deploy a .NET 7.0 SDK-type project which also references a SxS COM component.
Building and running the app works, incl. using the SxS COM object.

But when I try to publish the app via ClickOnce, the process fails with this exception: 
`(Interne Ausnahme #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Fehler bei der Veröffentlichung. Die Ursache des Fehlers konnte nicht ermittelt werden. Weitere Informationen finden Sie im Ausgabeprotokoll.` 
Basically: Something went wrong. :(

Comment: Great - reached a catch22. If I copy the component's SxS manifest to the application dir (it gets included for deployment), I can build the ClickOnce deployment. Installing the app fails because the manifest file already exists. If I exclude the SxS manifest, building the setup works as well, but then installation complains about the manifest missing.
So either way I cannot install the app! This is really screwed

Comment: It is possible to embed the manifest in the EXE using mt.exe, maybe that helps with the catch22...